# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import sleep
#set chromodriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(.5)
#launch URL
driver.get("https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-de-segmentos-e-setoriais/indice-imobiliario-imob-estatisticas-historicas.htm")
sleep(5)
sel = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'selectYear'))

#driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="selectYear"]"}
```

Hello, I'm having this issue trying to simply select a dropdown element from this page. I've tried many methods already and nothing has worked so far. Is anyone able to replicate what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the table is inside an Iframe, you need to switch to iframe first and then perform your regular actions.

which would look something like this

```py
sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.frame('bvmf_iframe')

sel = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'selectYear'))
```

You may want to increase the sleep timer based on how fast/slow your webpage will load.